# Set the location of the barcode with barbecue

Tags: java, awt, barcode, barbecue

The following prints my barcode (using [barbecue](https://sourceforge.net/projects/barbecue/))

```
try{
    Barcode b = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(info);

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(b);
    if (job.printDialog()){}
        job.print();
    }
}catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want now to set the location in the printed area.. I tried the following with different numbers but the output is the same.

```
Point p = new Point(10, 10); 
b.setLocation(p);
```

What am I missing?